# find most number of languages used

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called **soft** having a column name ‘**developin’** contains the name of language used to develop the software.
My requirement is that I need to find the name of language used most number of times
I used the following query :-

```
select developin, COUNT(developin) as 'total'
from software
group by developin
```

I am getting the list of all languages with their count. But not able get the name of that particular language having maximum count .
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to one most used language you can do

```
select top 1 developin, COUNT(developin) as 'total' 
from software 
group by developin
order by COUNT(developin) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

order by count(developin);

Comment: sorry i didn't try order by clause...now i got it where i was wrong thanks for your help.....